# Is Data.ByteString.Lazy append lazy?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
bs1 :: L.ByteString
bs2 :: L.ByteString
```

Is `L.append bs1 bs2` also lazy in that this will not cause me to consume all of bs1 immediately? Similarly with `L.concat` and unlike `L.length` which I understand will cause it to consume the entire bytestring because it needs to count all the bytes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple way of determining how lazy a function is, is to pass it partially defined values. For example, let's define a lazy bytestring of one chunk followed by an undefined tail.

```
*Main> let bs1 = L.fromChunks $ B.pack [102, 111, 111] : undefined
*Main> bs1
Chunk "foo" *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

As you can see, attempting to print it throws an exception after the first chunk. Now, let's define another lazy ByteString and try to append them.

```
*Main> let bs2 = L.pack [98, 97, 114]
*Main> L.append bs1 bs2
Chunk "foo" *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

`L.append` was able to produce the first chunk of the resulting lazy ByteString. This means that it only had to look at the first chunk of `bs1` to produce the first chunk of the result, i.e. it's as lazy as you would expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, append and concat are lazy, they'll only touch chunks when needed. The first chunk of bs1 is needed immediately, the second (if present) when the first is consumed etc.